# Firestore Query chaining using AND

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to chain the query parameters for Firestore. I want to dynamically add query parameters (along with some common ones). But it does not seem to be working. Is this a firestore limitation?

Chaining in the same line works:

```
db.collection("MY_COLLECTION")
                .whereEqualTo("user.firebaseUserId" , FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                .whereEqualTo("formId",formId)
                .whereEqualTo("user.active","true")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    FirestoreResponse response = new FirestoreResponse();
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          //getting results here - works!
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                });
```

But trying to add the conditions on the query object reference returns results only based on the 1st condition specified:

```
 Query firebaseQuery = collectionReference. whereEqualTo("user.firebaseUserId" , "myuserId"); //only this condition is applied
    firebaseQuery.whereEqualTo("user.active","true");

    if(someCondition){
         firebaseQuery.whereEqualTo("user.smart","true");
    }

firebaseQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                FirestoreResponse response = new FirestoreResponse();
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    //returns results only based on the 1st condition !!
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
```

This is strange since the .whereEqualTo returns a Query object.

I have also tried using CollectionReference.get() - along with adding query before to CollectionReference.

Comment: You should be able to do this.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries  Are you sure you have data that matches the requirements of your query?  Have you tried them each separately and verified each equality matches what you want?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue - I was reusing the same query object "firebaseQuery " and calling whereEqualTo on the same object.

The whereEqualTo needs to be called on the query object from previous step instead of using the first query ref.

```
    Query firebaseQuery1 = db.collection("MY_COLLECTION")
                    .whereEqualTo("user.firebaseUserId" , "someUserId");
            Query firebaseQuery2 = firebaseQuery1.whereEqualTo("formId",formId);
            Query firebaseQuery3 = firebaseQuery2.whereEqualTo("user.active","true");

 firebaseQuery3.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    FirestoreResponse response = new FirestoreResponse();
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          works now !!
                            //}
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                });
```